# Pulling current date in formula builder returns wrong date

Tags: 2010, infopath, date-time

I am trying to pull the current date in MMDDYY format from infopath so I can use concat with some other fields to autogenerate a request number, but I am receiving the incorrect date.  If I just use the `Today()` function I receive `9/30/2013`, the correct date, but if i use something like `concat(substring(addDays(today(), 42), 6, 2), substring(addDays(today(), 42), 9, 2), substring(addDays(today(), 42), 1, 4))` in order to remove the slashes it returns `11112013`. What is happening on the second request to cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfoPath is returning the correct result. You are adding 42 days to today's date, extract the day, month and year (4 digits) and then concatenate the day, month and year without any separators.

To see how a date is stored and represented in your system, put `today()` into a Calculated Value property. You will see something like `2013-09-30`

If you want the year with two digits, you need `substring(addDays(today(), 42), 3, 2)`, i.e. start with the third character and extract two digits. So the whole formula will be

```
concat(substring(addDays(today(), 42), 6, 2), substring(addDays(today(), 42), 9, 2), substring(addDays(today(), 42), 3, 2))
```

Comment: Apparently I misunderstood what the addDays function was doing in the example I was using.  4 digit year is fine, so 'concat(substring(today(), 6, 2), substring(today(), 9, 2), substring(today(), 1, 4))' worked perfectly. Thanks for your help.